# Derivative of the integral of a pull-back form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\omega$ be a $n$-form on the smooth compact manifold $M$ without boundary.
Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$ and $\phi_t$ the associated flow.
Let $A(t)=\int_M \phi_t^* \omega$. How can we compute $dA/dt$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is compact, every smooth top-dimensional form is integrable and furthermore the mapping $t\mapsto\omega(t):=\phi_t^*\omega$ is also smooth, so we can just differentiate the integrand. This is in principle justified by measure theory but you could also verify this by choosing an atlas and a partition of unity and then just use the according result for $\mathbb R^n$.

As a side remark, note that $\Omega^n(M)$ is a vector space (actually a $C^\infty(M)$-module), so the derivative of the curve $t\mapsto\omega(t)$ can be seen as an element of $\Omega^n(M)$ and thus can be integrated.

It is sufficient, however, to compute the derivative at $t=0$, due to the group action property of the flow. Then this is actually the definition of the Lie derivative:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\phi_t^*\omega =: \mathcal{L}_X\omega
$$
By Cartan's formula, we have
$$
\mathcal{L}_X\omega = i_Xd\omega + di_X\omega = di_X\omega,
$$
since $\omega$ is top-dimensional. Here the interiour product is $i_X\omega=\omega(X,\cdot,\dots,\cdot)$. Hence we have
$$
A'(0) = \int_M \mathcal{L}_X\omega = \int_M di_X\omega = \int_{\partial M} i_X\omega,
$$
which is zero if $M$ has no boundary.

Comment: Dear @Markus, does it implies that $dA=\omega$?

Comment: No, there are even different objects on both sides. $A$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}$, thus $dA=A'(t)dt$ is a 1-form on $\mathbb{R}$. $\omega$ is a curve in $\Omega^n(M)$, i.e. a parametrised family of $n$-forms on $M$. $dA$ is given by the computed derivative. At arbitrary $t$ we get because of the flow property and since pullbacks and exterior derivative commute: $$A'(t)= \int_M \frac{d}{ds}\big|_{s=0} \phi_{t+s}^*\omega = \int_M \phi_t^* \mathcal{L}_X\omega = \int_M d \phi_t^* i_X \omega = \int_{\partial M} \phi_t* i_X \omega$$